# Counting and printing location of duplicate words in a line using Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to read from a file and print out the location of duplicate words on each line.I have stored each line in an array, but I am not sure if this is the right way to start.

```
while (my $fileLine = <$fh>){
    my @lineWords = split /\s+/, $fileLine;
    print "@\n"
}
```

Comment: That should probably be `split ' '`, not `split /\s+/`.

Comment: I don't know the syntax of Perl but the idea is : take the first word of the line and loop over the rest of the line if you find a that the current word muches the first one increment a counter and so on do the same for the second word ... hope that helps :)

Comment: @Maraboc Depending on how "word" and "duplication" and "location" are defined, this might also be doable with a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while (<DATA>){
    chomp; # remove end of line chars
    my @wordsInLine = split /\s+/, $_;
    @wordsInLine = map {lc($_)} @wordsInLine; # convert words to lowercase
    my( $word, %wordsInLine, $n );
    for $word (@wordsInLine) {
       $wordsInLine{$word}++; # use hash %wordsInLine to count occurences of words
    }
    for $word (@wordsInLine) {
      $n++;
      if( (my $count = $wordsInLine{$word}||0) > 1 ) {
        print "line $.: Word $n \"$word\" is repeated $count times\n";
        delete($wordsInLine{$word}); # do not generate more than one report
                                     # about the same word in single line
      }
    }
}
__DATA__
This this is a sample sentence
A that That THAT !
```